# Is there a way to sign message by the Smart Contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development

I have a `public view` function that performs some calculations on the given input and returns the result. Although smart contracts don't have a private key Is there any way to add a signature as proof that output is generated by the smart contract?

Can a function in smart contract return output along with digital signature so the client can verify that output was generated by smart contract?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. It is EIP-1271: Standard Signature Validation Method for Contracts. You can [find details here](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1271).

EIP-1271 is supported e.g. by [Gnosis Multisig](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/search?q=1271).

Comment: as I read about [EIP-1271](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1271) it explains about `isValidSignature` for the signature verification. But how contract generates a digital signature for a given message?

Comment: `How contract generates a digital signature for a given message` It cannot do this without accessing Ethereum node. Whoever is responsible to check the validity of the message must call `isValidSignature` function. Thus, the validity of the signature is stored in the contract state. See https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/2620a21c0844f23df39ea98438b82e378bb334f0/contracts/handler/CompatibilityFallbackHandler.sol#L28

Comment: yes, I understood the  `isValidSignature` part. I am curious to know how can a contract generate its signature on a given input. As you mentioned `It cannot do this without accessing Ethereum node`. How can it be done by accessing the node?

Comment: Please study the linked Gnosis SAFE implementation. The contract simply has `mapping` signature -> true for valid signatures, but your contract is free to implement whatever checking scheme you want.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know if a smart contract can generate a signature. As far as I know, because no one has access to the private key of the smart contract, it's not possible to let the smart contract "sign" anything.

Comment: It depends on your definition of sign. If signing is defined as in EIP-1271 then it is possible to sign and most systems should be able to receive and verify these signatures.

Comment: Why is that a correct answer I don't understand.the question is clear. I need a smart contract to sign some arbitrary message like "I control this address". How do I do it?

Comment: Did you try to read the linked EIP? Which part of it you did not understand?